# Reset ActiveMQ after durable subscription has been registered

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have registered a durable subscription from my JMS Topic subscribers today. I did this by setting a unique client Id and a giving the subscription a subscription name:

```
connection.setClientId("worker" + this.pid);
session.createDurableSubscriber(xyzTopic, "xyzSubscription");
```

Now when I start my workers I am seeing the following error:

12/06/18 22:30:42 WARN broker.TransportConnection: Failed to add Connection ID:xxxxxx-45841-1340045847830-1:1, reason: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: worker2 already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:52796
12/06/18 22:30:42 WARN TransportConnection.Service: Async error occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add a producer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:xxxxxx-45841-1340045847830-1:1

(hostname replaced by xxxxxx)

I am still in the developing environment, and I though that when I restart ActiveMQ (using the maven goal activemq:run) then everything is reset. However this does not seem to be the case.

**Question:**
How can I reset the whole activeMQ and clear all persisted state such as durable subscriptions.

And also what exactly is causing this error? My clients do not display any exceptions, only activeMQ is showing the above error together with several identical exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more its hard to say what is causing the error, but to reset everything you can just delete the contents of the ./data/ directory where you installed ActiveMQ.

Comment: I am starting activeMQ via maven with activemq:run. Do you know where it keeps its data/ folder?
I have now solved the problem by renaming all clientIds and all subscription names. But I think that is not the cleanest solution.

Comment: did you try doing a mvn clean?  The data is probably in the target dir, but you can do a search for kahadb to find the files.

Comment: I can find neither a data directory nor any files named kahadb in the target directory.